# ComboBox current selection works if its setup from code behind but doesn't if in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I set the current selection like this, it doesn't work.

```
    <ComboBox Name="combo2" SelectedItem="Two">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
        <ComboBoxItem  Content="Three"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

But if I setup the ComboBox like below, then it works.

```
    <ComboBox Name="combo2" SelectedItem="Two">
    </ComboBox>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<String> Items = new List<string>
        {
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
        };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        combo2.ItemsSource = Items; 
    }
}
```

I thought both way of setting up ComboBox is essentially the same. Why does current selection is set in one case but not the other?

Comment: Which one not work, SelectedItem or ItemsSource?

Comment: If you using SelectedIndex Instead of SelectedItem you can take current item in list.

Comment: You can rather use [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex) if you know item index. Neigher of approaches is considered good (how you plan to retrieve results of user selection?). Look into MVVM and use bindings instead of manipulating UI elements in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same. In one case the `SelectedItem` is of type `ComboBoxItem` in another `String`. This will work and is the same:

```
<ComboBox Name="combo2" SelectedItem="Two" xmlns:Sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="Sys:String">
            <Sys:String>One</Sys:String>
            <Sys:String>Two</Sys:String>
            <Sys:String>Three</Sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

or if you want to have it with `ComboBoxItem` you should use `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` accordingly:

```
<ComboBox Name="combo2"  SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="Two">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
    <ComboBoxItem  Content="Three"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `SelectedItem` must be present among the values in `Items`.

In your first case, there is no *string* "Two" among the items. In the second example, it is. In other words; the types matter. A `ComboBoxItem` is not a `string` and vice versa.

If you want to selected the second item regardless of the type, you could use the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
<ComboBox Name="combo2" SelectedIndex="1">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
    <ComboBoxItem  Content="Three"/>
</ComboBox>
```